# can't calculate TCP checksum and get the result as in wireshark

Tags: networking, tcp, checksum

I am trying to calculate the checksum of a tcp packet and I can't get the same value as in the packet captured with wireshark

the original captured packet is:
"6c f0 49 e8 a3 0d 24 b6 fd 52 40 cb 08 00 45 00 00 28 02 22 40 00 80 06 00 00 00 0a 2a 00 1c 1f 0d 5a 24 ca 7d 01 bb 3f 44 f8 6e 6c 83 75 20 50 10 01 02 83 91 00 00"

As I saw in wireshark:
The first 14 bytes are ETH.
After that (in the IP part) there are 12 bytes of "header length",'DSCP','total length,'identification','fragment offset','TTL','protocol','header checksum'.
and then there are 4 bytes of IP-src and 4 bytes of IP-dst (which are the only one in the IP header that are important for the calculation).
we are left with 20 bytes of TCP header (no data).

I created the new packet for the calculation with the pseudo header in the form:
IPsrc/IPdst/reserved(0x00)/protocol(0x06)/TCP-length(0x0014)/TCP-header

Which got me:
"0a 2a 00 1c 1f 0d 5a 24 00 06 00 14 ca 7d 01 bb 3f 44 f8 6e 6c 83 75 20 50 10 01 02 83 91 00 00"

Zeroing the tcp checksum field (the 0x8391 according to wireshark) gets:
"0a 2a 00 1c 1f 0d 5a 24 00 06 00 14 ca 7d 01 bb 3f 44 f8 6e 6c 83 75 20 50 10 01 02 00 00 00 00"

calculating checksum on the new packet got me the value: 0xcc45 which is differen than the one in the original packet (0x8391)

```
data="0a 2a 00 1c 1f 0d 5a 24 00 06 00 14 ca 7d 01 bb 3f 44 f8 6e 6c 83 75 20 50 10 01 02 00 00 00 00"  
def carry_around_add(a, b):  
    c = a + b  
    return (c & 0xffff) + (c >> 16)  

def checksum(msg):  
    s = 0  
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):  
        w = ord(msg[i]) + (ord(msg[i+1]) << 8)  
        s = carry_around_add(s, w)  
    return ~s & 0xffff  

data = data.split()  
data = map(lambda x: int(x,16), data)  
data = struct.pack("%dB" % len(data), *data)  

print ' '.join('%02X' % ord(x) for x in data)  
print "Checksum: 0x%04x" % checksum(data)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: TCP checksums have nothing whatsoever to do with OSI. There is an RFC that provides C code for the TCP checksum. If you're not using that you should be, and as you have neither provided your own code nor even specified a language it is impossible to see what this question is actually about.

Answer (score 0):

Your total test data length is 55 bytes, it should be 14 (ETH) + 20 (IP) + 20 (TCP). It's not that it's just one byte too long since that would not match with the 0x8391 checksum. But, the IP Protocol byte (0x06 - TCP) at IP offset 9 is stil in place. The IP source address seems rather unlikely though: 0.10.40.0.

The 'which got me' part starts with '0a 2a' which are the 2nd and 3rd byte of the IP source address. So let's assume the three zero bytes before this address should actually be two zero bytes. If that's correct, we're still on the right track.

The 12 byte TCP pseudo-header is: IPsrc/IPdst/0x00/0x06/TCP-length(0x0014) (without the TCP header), so far so good. The TCP checksum is calculated over: pseudo-header + TCP header + TCP data. But your test data uses only the pseudo-header and the TCP header data, the TCP data itself is missing.

I didn't really check your Python code but I don't see any obvious problems. The main issue seems to be the lack of the TCP payload data in the calculation.